# Node.js Cluster can you run multiple workers on single core

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Digital Ocean server that I want to run Node.js on, but it only has 1 cpu. Can I run Node.js with the cluster module and have multiple workers running on a single core machine?  I am trying to understand the limitations of cluster. All of the code I see only creates one worker per CPU, but I didnt know if it is possible to run more than one per cpu.

Comment: You'll ultimately be bound by the threading, cores, and speed of the CPU. You can run multiple instances of Node on a single CPU[core], but the i/o will eventually hit hard limitations of of the hardware and instance threads will be queued accordingly.

Comment: @brandonscript So would it be correct to assume it functions and is bound similar to a threaded application?

Comment: Yes — Node is a single-threaded application; while it's event-loop is non-blocking, the process itself is bound to a single thread. Run multiple instances on a single-threaded CPU and things will slow down accordingly.

Comment: Does that mean that all of the workers that the Cluster module spins up are on the same thread as the master? I thought they would be different threads.